# Can i speed up my React and Type project using webpack?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I have a project and it's huge. And when I write npm start it takes 6 to 8 minutes to load. Is it possible to make it so that you can first quickly load the sign in page, and only then everything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this question correctly, would need some specifics of the project like

- How is it structured ?
- Is it decoupled enough ?
- Can components work separately from each other ?

Nevertheless, if its only a signup page, I assume there will be a simple input form and a network call for authorization.

To make this work, extract the component responsible for authentication into a single component, and if the component has some extra dependencies, try to lazy load them with lazy imports

```js
import { lazy } from 'react';

const later_package = lazy(() => { import './later_dependency'})
```

Note: the above lazy import only works with default imports.

- more about code splitting [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html)

for webpack do some bundle analysis for the bundle check if the bundle dependencies are what are slowing down the build. If not, split the entry points. More about Webpack code-splitting [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#bundle-analysis)

Comment: thank you. I dont know about structured. but its huge. all i now its is so slow and it decoupled. but sing in form have the separate dependencec from react-hook-form adn a lot of custom hook. right now i'm just a trainee. and i want to now how can i optimizied project

Comment: Okay, simply said "code-splitting" is a way of reducing the number of "things" loaded on your app/site at once. It will help you in chopping the project into smaller parts. Try to make some boundaries in the project with questions like.
- would this be loaded at once ?
- can an import be done later ?
- is this component used here or not ?
This will help you know where to chop the project into parts and then lazy load it.

Comment: i'll tried. thx a lot.